# Why does React discard the entire DOM subtree and recreate it from scratch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There are two helpers that can be used to add content while rendering:

```
  ...

  const DisplayA = () => <div className={'containerA'}>
    <button onClick={handleToggleA}>{"A toggled: " + toggledA.toString()}</button>
  </div>

  const displayB = () => <div className={'containerB'}>
    <button onClick={handleToggleB}>{"B toggled: " + toggledB.toString()}</button>
  </div>

  return (
    <>
      <DisplayA />
      { displayB() }
    </>
  );

  ...
```

The problem is that in the first helper, React always discards the entire subtree and creates it again from scratch, as can be seen here:

[image: subtree is discarded and recreated]

[**The demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-inline-function-subtree-discard-test-s8hku)

I know, the first way is syntax sugar for React.createElement so a new component is created each render. However, the second way, a distinct arrow function is created each render too.

1. Why does React not know how to reuse the subtree the first way but does know the second way? What is happening **under the hood**?
2. How can we spot when the DOM subtree is discarded and recreated each render? Is it enough to assume that one should not create inline components, and use inline functions only?

Notice, that helpers can come from props, for example (render props pattern).

Comment: There's a couple of answers to your question now, are either suitable, or do you need something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will depend in which scope `DisplayA` is defined. Functional components should usually be defined at the top level of a file. In your demo `DisplayA` is a component that is created inside the `render` of `App`, so every time `App` renders a new functional component is created, not a new invocation of the same component.

To resolve this make `DisplayA` top level in the file and pass props through to it.

```
const DisplayA = ({handleToggle, toggled}) => <div className={'containerA'}>
  <button onClick={handleToggle}>{"A toggled: " + toggled.toString()} </button>
</div>

const App = () => {
  ...
  return <>
    <DisplayA handleToggle={() => {...}} toggle={...} />
  </>
}
```

The second approach does not create a component which is passed to react for reconciliation, but is a function which is invoked while rendering and puts the contained elements into the rendering of this component.

Comment: To be more precise, if the functions are equal `oldElement === newElement`, then it will re-use  the old element tree

Comment: Thanks this helped me in a related issue where images would refetch from the server. As the images are hosted on aws s3 this was causing me potential costs. Moving the component which loads the images as a top level component fixed it

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you are not calling `DisplayA`. Instead, you are letting react decide when to render it. Notice how when transpiled, `React.createElement(DisplayA)` does not invoke this function. When react renders the subtree, it decides what needs to be re-rendered.

The process of handling tree changes/updates is called reconciliation. In [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#elements-of-different-types) it says that same types will try to maintain state, whereas different component types will always perform a tear down on the DOM tree.

The latter happens with your `DisplayA` component because it's a different value on every render. Although the component renders the same view, React can't be sure that this is the same component because the value `DisplayA` points to a different component reference each time. In this case you are using function components, therefore the value is a reference to a new function. The variable name just happens to be the same - it does not have any importance at run time.

In the second case with `displayB` you are explicitly calling the function and rendering its result. Because the function is pure, this is equivalent to pulling its return value and inlining it inside the parent component:

```
return (
  <>
    <DisplayA />
    { 
      <div className={'containerB'}>
        <button onClick={handleToggleB}>{"B toggled: " + toggledB.toString()}</button>
      </div>
    }
  </>
)
```

Notice how the second child of this fragment is now a `div`. Because `div`s are primitive elements, they are represented by the literal string `'div'` and not a reference to a component. React knows between renders that this is the same tree and as such does not destroy it. This would also work if you had any external component with a stable reference - it will be considered an element of the [same type](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#component-elements-of-the-same-type).