# Unexpected behaviour : function vs functional component and animations

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I display a list of foos and when i click on some link *more results* i keep the existing foos and i append to them the new ones from my api like bellow

```
const [foos, setFoos] = useState([]);
...
// api call with axios
...
success: (data) => {
    setFoos([ ...foos, ...data ])
},
```

Each  `<Foo />` component run the animation above

App.js

```
...
<div className="foos-results">
    { foos.map((foo, index) => <Foo {...{ foo, index }} key={foo.id}/>) }
</div>
...
```

Foo.js

```
const Foo = ({ foo, index }) => <div className="circle">...</div>
```

animation.css

```
.circle {
   ...
   animation: progress .5s ease-out forwards;
}
```

The problem is when i append the new ones then the animation is triggered for all the lines of `<Foo />`.

The behavior expected is that the animation is triggered just for the new ones and not starting over with the existing ones too.

**UPDATE**

We have found the origin of the problem (it's not related to the uniqueness of `key={foo.id}`)

if we change

```
const Foo = ({ foo, index }) => <div className="circle">...</div>
```

to

```
const renderFoo = ({ foo, index }) => <div className="circle">...</div>
```

And App.js to

```
...
<div className="foos-results">
    { foos.map((foo, index) => renderFoo({ foo, index })) }
</div>
...
```

It works

So why is this behavior like this in react ?

here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-galileo-dh50m) based on @Jackyef code

Comment: Since you are assigning unique `key` to each `Foo` component, React should preserve part of the list that has already been rendered and prevent re-triggering the animation. The code you share here looks correct enough to me. Where is the element that has the `circle` class? Maybe it has something to do with the css class or something else inside the `Foo` component.

Comment: @ClaireLin  the element that has the `circle` is inside `Foo` component, i update my question

Comment: Hmm I don't see any problem with your code. Could you make a sandbox version recreating the issue?

Comment: Can you show us the code for Foo component, and also can you confirm if `foo.id` is stable? If it is stable, react would not recreate the `divs` and the animation should not replay. Here is a sandbox showing the behavior: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-bell-bfi69

Comment: @Jackyef even if you delete the `key={item.id}` in your example it still works (with a warning), so it's not a problem of `foo.id` stability

Comment: @Jackyef i update my question

Comment: Yes, if you remove the key it still works. But if the value of the key change between render, it will not work. No keys is different with changing keys in this case. But anyway, you are right. This particular problem was not caused by `key` instability. I have written an answer to explain this @Youssef

Comment: React does a rerender every time a change is made hence it seems like it how react works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite an interesting one.

Let's look at the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-galileo-dh50m) provided in the question.

Inside `App`, we can see this.

```
  const renderItems = () => (
    <div>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <div className="item" key={item.id}>
          <span>
            {index + 1}. {item.value}
          </span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );

  const Items = () => renderItems();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>List of items</h1>
      <button onClick={addItem}>Add new item</button>
      <Items />
    </div>
  );
```

Seems pretty harmless right? The problem with this is that `Items` is declared in the `App` render function. This means that on each render, `Items` actually is now a different function, even though what it does is the same.

`<Items />` is transpiled into `React.createElement`, and when diffing, React  takes into account each components' referential equality to decide whether or not it is the same component as previous render. If it's not the same, React will think it's a different component, and if it's different, it will just create and mount a new component. This is why you are seeing the animation being played again.

If you declare `Items` component outside of `App` like this:

```
const Items = ({ items }) => (
  <div>
    {items.map((item, index) => (
      <div className="item" key={item.id}>
        <span>
          {index + 1}. {item.value}
        </span>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);

function App() { /* App render function */}
```

You will see everything works as expected. [Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-mirzakhani-xw3th?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

So, to summarise:

1. Referential equality matters to React when diffing
2. Components (function or class that returns JSX) should be stable. If they change between renders, React will have a hard time due to point number 1.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to disable this re-rendering animation, but I think there is a workaround that could solve this issue.

As we know that each div's css is reloaded every time, so the solution I can think of, is to create another css class rule (let this class be named  'circle_without_anim') with same css as class 'circle' but without that animation and while appending new div, just before appending change class of all divs that have class name 'circle' to 'circle_without_anim' that would make the changes and css to previous divs but just without that animation and the append this new div with class 'circle' making it the only div that have animation.

Formally the algorithm will be like:

1. Write another css class(different name for example prev_circle) with same rules as 'circle' but without the animation rule.
2. In Javascript just before appending new div with class 'circle', change class of all previous divs that have class named 'circle' to newly created class 'prev_circle' that do not have animation rule.
3. Append the new div with class 'circle'.

Result: It would give an illusion that the CSS of previous divs is not being reloaded as the css is same but without animation, but the new div has different css rule (animation rule) which is going to be reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

With this code:

```
const Items = () => renderItems();
...
<Items />
```

React has no chance of knowing that `Items` in the current render is the same component as `Items` in the previous render.

Consider this:

```
A = () => renderItems()
B = () => renderItems()
```

A and B are different components, so if you have `<B />` in the current render and `<A />` instead of `<B />` in the previous render, React will discard the subtree rendered by `<A />` and render it again.

You are invoking `React.createElement` (since `<Items />` is just a JSX syntax sugar for `React.createElement(Items, ...)`) every render, so React scraps the old `<Items />` in the DOM tree and creates it again each time.

Check out [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507656/why-does-react-discard-the-entire-dom-subtree-and-recreate-it-from-scratch) for more details.

There are two solutions:

- create `Items` component outside of the render function (as Jackyef suggested)
- use render function (`{ renderItems() }` instead of `<Items />`)