# React functional component re-renders whole component if defined in another functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, react-functional-component

```
const List = props => {
  const SubList = (number, key) => <p key={number}>{number}</p>;

  const WholeList = () => props.numbers.map(SubList);

  // method 1 return (<WholeList/>)
  // method 2 return props.numbers.map(SubList);
};

function App() {
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setNumbers([...numbers, numbers.length + 1])}>
        Plus one
      </button>
      <List numbers={numbers} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Method 1 and 2 renders exactly the same thing except their re-render behaviour is different.

In Method 1 when I click on Plus One and inspect DOM, I found the whole list re-rendered. If instead I use Method 2 only newly added numbers are inserted into DOM. I found both have their use cases but I am unsure about the behaviour. Can anyone shed light upon this behaviour? Could the confusion arise from the fact that I have never used class-component in React before?

I have a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-u39ow) example here!

Answer (score 0):

I found my question is a duplicate of [Why does React discard the entire DOM subtree and recreate it from scratch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507656/why-does-react-discard-the-entire-dom-subtree-and-recreate-it-from-scratch])

In short, functional component defined in a rendering component will be recreated every time. React cannot differentiate rendering result from old and new function although both renders the same thing.

React can however look at the props change and decide if a functional component should be rerendered.

In my original question, `const WholeList = () => props.numbers.map(SubList);` is defined in `List` therefore it is recreated every time `List` rerenders. React cannot reliably tell if the `WholeList` has changed or not thus rerenders it.

In case 2, the rendering result is deterministic which is a list of `<p>`. React can compare the previous and the new result. Please see react [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html).

Answer (score 0):

simply because "method 1 return ()" by doing so, you treated WholeList as a functional component, because FC re-renders on every state change, therefore, you see the result.

Answer (score 0):

To make it very clear, there are a few steps React needs to go through to decide if UI needs to be updated:

Whenever there is a state change in the parent component

1. `render` function is called in all its descendants
2. React applies diffing algorithm on each re-rendered component to compare the old state and new state
3. If the result of step 2 is different, update the UI

How the diffing algorithm works is that it compares the `type` of the old and new state of the component created by `React.createElement(type, config, children)`.

1. If the `type` are different, React will tear down the old tree and build the new tree from scratch
2. If the `type` remains the same, React will continue to compare the `config` or props and updates the changed attributes in DOM.

In the case below, `WholeList` is defined as a function, which leads to a new function being created and assigned to `type`, in which React determines the `type` has changed and rebuilds the component tree entirely in DOM.

```
const List = props => {
  const SubList = (number, key) => <p key={number}>{number}</p>;

  const WholeList = () => props.numbers.map(SubList);

  return <WholeList/>;
};
```

To avoid the undesired behaviour, you can return a JSX element instead

```
const List = props => {
  const SubList = (number, key) => <p key={number}>{number}</p>;

  const WholeList = props.numbers.map(SubList);

  return WholeList;
};
```

In this way, React compares a list of elements with type `p` and be able to tell which is the newly added element among the list since last state, then updates accordingly in the DOM.

**You might also want to know**

A static component can be re-rendered, but not necessarily updated in the DOM. In this context, re-render means executing the `render` function. Considering this in your example:

```
function App() {
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setNumbers([...numbers, numbers.length + 1])}>
        Plus one
      </button>
      <List numbers={numbers} />
      <h1>I'm static</h1> {/*this element will be re-rendered on state changes too*/}
    </>
  );
}
```

Why doesn't React update the static component in the DOM? Because the diffing algorithm can tell the component hasn't changed by following the rules stated above. React manages to calculate the difference quite efficiently, so it won't be an issue. If you want the `render` function to execute in the static components for once ever, make them functional component and use `React.memo`.